# Splitting images into distinct subimages in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I have some python code (using the pillow module) which converts an image to a series of silhouettes, as shown below, this code works completely fine.

I'm doing this with the intention of splitting the original image into a series of sub images.

I'm totally stuck on how to go about detecting which areas are clusters & should be cropped into their own sub images, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

[image: start image]
[image: silhouette images]

Comment: Scikit-image has tons of [examples](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_polygon.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-edges-plot-polygon-py). You're basically looking for object/edge detection.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? Do you want to extract each leave in black color ? If so, you could do it with numpy as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60780831/python-how-to-cut-out-an-area-with-specific-color-from-image-opencv-numpy

Comment: @Rivers I'm trying to extract each leaf in rgb, I converted them to black as I thought it'd be easier to determine the edges, thank you though! I'll take a look

Comment: You can also use https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html on your black and white image to get each leaf as a subimage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way of doing it:

This code will extract areas (parts) of an image.
We commonly refer to this as "regions of interest extraction" (ROIs extraction) or sometimes "areas of interest extraction".

First, we apply some operations on the source image, in order to find precise contours of the object we want to extract. Then based on these contours, we extract the parts of the image we want.

With your example BMerz, it will output each green leave in a separate file.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Source image
source_image_path = "leaves.png"
source_image_name, ext =  source_image_path.split(".")

# Load the image
source_image = cv2.imread(source_image_path)

# Convert image to grayscale
grayscale_image = cv2.cvtColor(source_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Save the image
cv2.imwrite((source_image_name + "_grayscale." + ext), grayscale_image)

# Remove gaussian noise
denoised_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayscale_image,(3,3),0)

# Detect edges
#160 and 210 : min and max thresholds. Look at the saved image after tweakings, in order to find the right values.
edges = cv2.Canny(denoised_image, 160, 210)

# Save the image
cv2.imwrite((source_image_name + "_edges." + ext), edges)


# Use erode and dilate to remove unwanted edges and close gaps of some edges
# Again, tweak the kernel values as needed

# Erode will make the edges thinner. If the kernel size is big, some edges will be removed.
# (1,1) will erode a little, (2,2) will erode more, (5,5) will erode even more...
kernel = np.ones((1,1), np.uint8)
eroded_edges = cv2.erode(edges, kernel, iterations = 10)

# dilate will smooth the edges
# (1,1) will dilate a little, (2,2) will dilate more, (5,5) will dilate even more...
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
dilated_edges = cv2.dilate(eroded_edges, kernel, iterations = 1)


# Find contours
# Use a copy of the image: findContours alters the image
dilated_edges_copy = dilated_edges.copy()
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(dilated_edges_copy, 127, 255, 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# We could have used v2.RETR_EXTERNAL and CHAIN_APPROX_NONE too

# Create a list containing only the contours parents from the hierarchy returned by findContours
hierarchy_parents_only = [x[3] for x in hierarchy[0]]

print("Number of contours found: ", len(contours))
print("Number of hierarchies found: ", len(hierarchy_parents_only))


# Now we will filter the contours. We select only the ones we need.
selected_contours = list()
selected_hierarchy = list()
min_area = 100

for index,contour in enumerate(contours):
    # Keep only contours having no parent (remove overlapping contours
    if hierarchy_parents_only[index] == -1:
        # Keep only contours having an area greater than "min_area"
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if area > min_area:
            selected_contours.append(contour)
            selected_hierarchy.append(hierarchy[0][index])

print("Number of selected contours: ", len(selected_contours))
print("Number of selected hierarchies : ", len(selected_hierarchy))


# Draw all contours on the source image (usefull for debugging, but change color (0, 0, 0) to something else if the background is black too).
# -1 means drawing all contours, "(0, 255, 0)" for contours in green color, "3" is the thickness of the contours
source_image_with_contours = cv2.drawContours(source_image, selected_contours, -1, (0, 0, 0), 3) 

# Save the image
cv2.imwrite((source_image_name + "_with_contours." + ext), source_image_with_contours)


# Now, extract each image
for index,contour in enumerate(selected_contours):

    # Image name for writing to file
    cropped_image_path = source_image_name + "_" + str(index) + "." + ext

    # Create mask where white is what we want, black otherwise
    mask = np.zeros_like(grayscale_image)

    # Draw filled contour in mask
    cv2.drawContours(mask, selected_contours, index, 255, -1)

    # Mask everything but the object we want to extract
    masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(source_image, source_image, mask=mask)
    cv2.imwrite("out2.jpg", masked_image)
    
    # Determine the bounding box (minimum rectangle in which the object can fit)
    (y, x) = np.where(mask == 255)
    (top_y, top_x) = (np.min(y), np.min(x))
    (bottom_y, bottom_x) = (np.max(y), np.max(x))

    # Crop image (extract)
    extracted_image = masked_image[top_y:bottom_y+1, top_x:bottom_x+1]

    # Write to file
    cv2.imwrite(cropped_image_path, extracted_image)
```

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, but this works fantastically! thank you !