# Python: use OpenCV to extract object inside a shape

Tags: python, opencv

I need to extract the image from inside this rectangular box using python OpenCV.

[image]

I've seen and tried several ways of extracting content from inside a shape, but each has a limitation. Most examples have a shape with a high contrast, solid color such as green (0,255,0) or red(255,0,0). However, my problem is that the red box has some transparency/opaqueness making the identification of the rectangle much more difficult. Red pixel color for the rectangle ranges from 175-220, but the rest of the image also has similar tones of red making the extraction even more difficult.

[image]

I'm fairly new to OpenCV, so any assistance is greatly appreciated. I've tried both of the solutions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60780831/python-how-to-cut-out-an-area-with-specific-color-from-image-opencv-numpy) thread, but neither produces the desired result.

Comment: Can you post original image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

1. **Convert** image to `HSV`
2. **Threshold on red** to segment the rectangle
3. Apply some **morphology** to close the contour as much as possible
4. Detect **external contours**
5. Filter noisy blobs based on **area**; You are looking for the largest contour
6. Get the contour's **bounding rectangle**
7. **Slice** the image using the bounding rectangle

Let's see the code:

```
# imports:
import cv2
import numpy as np

# image path
path = "D://opencvImages//"
fileName = "uHNzL.jpg"

# Reading an image in default mode:
inputImage = cv2.imread(path + fileName)
# Deep copy for results:
inputImageCopy = inputImage.copy()

# Convert the image to the HSV color space:
hsvImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Set the HSV values:
lowRange = np.array([144, 105, 0])
uppRange = np.array([179, 255, 255])

# Create the HSV mask
binaryMask = cv2.inRange(hsvImage, lowRange, uppRange)
```

This is the mask:

[image]

As you see the rectangle is (mostly) there. Let's try to improve the contour with some morphology. Some dilations followed by erosions should do the trick:

```
# Apply Dilate + Erode:
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
binaryMask = cv2.morphologyEx(binaryMask, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel, iterations=3)
binaryMask = cv2.morphologyEx(binaryMask, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel, iterations=3)
```

This is the result:

[image]

The rectangle is a little bit bigger, but so does the noise. However, we are looking for the biggest blob, so we can filter by area. Let's crop the largest blob:

```
# Find the target blobs on the binary mask:
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binaryMask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Alright, just look for the outer bounding boxes:
for _, c in enumerate(contours):

    # Get blob area:
    blobArea = cv2.contourArea(c)

    # Set minimum area:
    minArea = 1000

    if blobArea > minArea:
        # Get the bounding rectangle:
        boundRect = cv2.boundingRect(c)

        # Bondary offset:
        offset = 15

        # Draw the rectangle on the input image:
        # Get the dimensions of the bounding rect:
        rectX = int(boundRect[0] + offset)
        rectY = int(boundRect[1] + offset)
        rectWidth = int(boundRect[2] - 2 * offset)
        rectHeight = int(boundRect[3] - 2 * offset)

        #  Green Color, detected blobs:
        color = (0, 255, 0)
        cv2.rectangle(inputImageCopy, (int(rectX), int(rectY)),
                      (int(rectX + rectWidth), int(rectY + rectHeight)), color, 2)

        # Crop contour:
        croppedImage = inputImage[rectY:rectY + rectHeight, rectX:rectX + rectWidth]
        cv2.imshow("croppedImage", croppedImage)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

    cv2.imshow("Rectangles", inputImageCopy)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Now, because we are processing a morphed image, the rectangle binary outline is a little bit bigger than the actual red rectangle, so I introduce an offset to crop the image a little bit tighter.

This is the bounding rectangle with an offset of `15` pixels:

[image]

This is the cropped image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the assistance; it was extremely help! I did have to modify the code to generalize it enough to apply it to millions of images. I am getting about 95%+ accuracy. Errors include images where multiple buildings are in close proximity with red roof, dark red soil, vehicles... basically anything red. Hence, I increased the threshold (minArea) to a high value to exclude large red objects outside of the encompassed red box. Hope this helps other people.

Major changes...

1. I removed the offset, it did not generalize well enough, in some images the desired contents were cut out of the final product.
2. I did have to combine contours to avoid having lots of smaller rectangles, which is also the reason I increased the minArea threshold. I found that even a small decrement of 100 sometimes produced 2+ contours, so I had to combine them before calculating the bounding rectangle.
3. super important, I created an upper and lower color range to ensure that I was getting the entire area encompassed by the red box. Because of the red box's transparency, the hue and saturation were all over the place, this helped to always ensure that I captured what was needed.

Hope this helps others.

```py
# Original image
src = cv2.imread(img_file, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB )

# HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

# lower boundary RED color range values; Hue (0 - 10)
lower1 = np.array([0, 100, 20])
upper1 = np.array([10, 255, 255])
 
# upper boundary RED color range values; Hue (160 - 180)
lower2 = np.array([160,100,20])
upper2 = np.array([179,255,255])
 
lower_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower1, upper1)
upper_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower2, upper2)
 
binaryMask = lower_mask + upper_mask

# kernel dialation and erode
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
binaryMask = cv2.morphologyEx(binaryMask, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel, iterations=3)
binaryMask = cv2.morphologyEx(binaryMask, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel, iterations=3)

# Find the target blob
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binaryMask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                       cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
flag = True
minArea = 50_000
while flag and minArea > 100:
    contours_ = [contour for contour in contours
                if cv2.contourArea(contour) > minArea]
    contoursAreas = [cv2.contourArea(contour) for contour in contours]

    if contours_:
        contour = np.vstack(contours_)
        flag = False
    else:
        minArea -= 500

# blob to bounding rectangle
offset = 15
boundRect = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
rectX = int(boundRect[0])
rectY = int(boundRect[1])
rectWidth = int(boundRect[2])
rectHeight = int(boundRect[3])

# Crop orignal image and save image
croppedImage = src[rectY:rectY + rectHeight, rectX:rectX + rectWidth]
imgFName = os.path.split(img_file)[-1]
imgFPath = os.path.join(OUT_IMG_PATH, imgFName)
cv2.imwrite(imgFPath, croppedImage)
```